# Select data from table and if they repeat add it in new column

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have:

```
ID  SKU PRODUCT
=======================
1   FOO-23  Orange
2   BAR-23  Orange
3   FOO-24  Apple
4   FOO-25  Orange
5   BAR-24  Apple
```

I want

```
Orange FOO-23  BAR-23  FOO-25   
Apple FOO-24   Bar-24
```

What kind of query do I have to use?

Comment: Google "MySQL dynamic pivot".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select product, group_concat(SKU separator ' ' ) as skus
from your_table
group by product
```